# Ubuntu hangs at shutdown since changed from 16.04 to 18.04

Tags: dual-boot, shutdown

I'm using an MSI laptop, specifically the model [GP72-2QE Leopard Pro](https://www.msi.com/Laptop/GP72-2QE-Leopard-Pro/Specification).
Since I bought it, I have used Ubuntu and Windows 10, in dual boot, with UEFI and GPT disk partitions.  With 12.04 and 16.04 LTS, I had no problems at all; everything worked just fine.

I reformatted the Ubuntu partition, and installed Ubuntu 18.04. Ever since, this PC will not shutdown; it will restart OK. Upgrading to 19.04 did not solve the problem.

I searched this problem; many articles recommended that I change my option in GRUB (like `acpi=off, nomodeset=0`), but nothing worked.

It hangs with message `reboot:powerdown`, but it feels like Ubuntu shut down but didn't power off the PC since I hear the disk drive turn off; only the fan keeps working.

I have this problem for about a year now and something I noticed is if I `mount` and `umount` my second drive (windows installation drive) my computer will power off fine(sometimes not always), maybe its just a coincidence.

How may I troubleshoot this problem?

Update-20/6/19

I noticed that my laptop shutdowns normally if unplug my mouse before, it happened twice today, any thoughts?

Comment: Try to do it from the terminal once. To shutdown: `sudo shutdown now`. Also try: `sudo shutdown -r now`  which will restart the machine. Sometimes one will hang and not the other which may help diagnose the problem further. Let us know what you find.

Comment: Hello jwcooper thanks for answering so fast. I tried both of them it hanged on the first but not on the second command. I also tried "sudo powerdoff" which also hanged.